# Select 1 row after group by multiple columns SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with ids,versions,timestamp and I need to get the latest version for each id where the number of versions in more than 1.

For example

```
123 1.5 2015-03-28 08:21:04.563
123 1.4 2015-02-28 08:21:04.563
234 1.5 2015-06-28 08:21:04.563
234 1.4 2015-05-28 08:21:04.563
234 1.3 2015-04-28 08:21:04.563
345 1.5 2015-01-28 08:21:04.563
```

In the above data id 123 and 234 have more than 1 version.I need to get the max(timestamp) along with the id and version

Output

```
123 1.5 2015-03-28 08:21:04.563
234 1.5 2015-06-28 08:21:04.563
```

I have the following sql that will give me 1 row for each id,however I need to exclude ids with only 1 version.

```
 ;with versions as
(
    select  id, 
            version, 
            row_no = row_number() over (partition by id order by max(dt_create) desc), 
            dt_create = max(dt_create)
    from table_name
    group by id, version
)
select id,version,row_no, dt_create
from versions
where row_no=1
order by id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an aggregate in the row_number. Also, you would want to use the `IN` clause to limit the ID's you stated.

As a side note, row_number is much faster than aggregations which is used in other answers. Good choice of you in the original query.

```
 ;with versions as
(
    select  id, 
            version, 
            row_no = row_number() over (partition by id order by dt_create desc) 
    from table_name
)
select id,version,row_no, dt_create
from versions
where row_no=1 and id in (select id from versions where row_no > 1)
order by id
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
    ;with mycte as (
select 123 as ID, 1.5 as version, '2015-03-28 08:21:04.563' as timestamp
union all 
select 123, 1.4, '2015-02-28 08:21:04.563'
union all 
select 234, 1.5, '2015-06-28 08:21:04.563'
union all 
select 234, 1.4, '2015-05-28 08:21:04.563'
union all 
select 234, 1.3, '2015-04-28 08:21:04.563'
union all 
select 345, 1.5, '2015-01-28 08:21:04.563'
)

Select ID
, max(version) as version
, max(timestamp) as timestamp
,count(*) as total
 from mycte
 group by ID
 having count(*) >1
```

Comment: No need for the `count(*)` in the select, but great answer

Comment: @AaronDietz Thanks.. agree there is no need for count(*), but was only showing the OP what was happening and why the having was included.. :)

Comment: A problem with this approach could be that if would return incorrect data if the higher version has for some reason a lower timestamp than a previous version (if all versions have a higher or equal timestamp than previous versions, then there is no problem).

Answer (score 0):

Your query is close.  Add `HAVING` clause to exclude records that only have one version

```
;with versions as
(
    select  id, 
            version, 
            row_no = row_number() over (partition by id order by max(dt_create) desc), 
            dt_create = max(dt_create)
    from table_name
    group by id, version
    having COUNT(*) > 1
)
select id,version,row_no, dt_create
from versions
where row_no=1
order by id
```